# How to swap two variables in one line in C?

Tags: c

I want to know that is there any other way of swapping 2 numbers in one line and of course without 3rd variable.

I know one way of doing this:

```
b=a+b-(a=b)
```

or

```
a=a+b-(b=a)
```

both are same(approximately). If you know then please help me out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Making code unreadable just to avoid using a 3rd variable

Comment: `a/=b=(a=a*b)/b;` Multiplication and division instead of addition and subtraction?

Comment: Both of your example methods invoke undefined behavior in C, as you are modifying a variable and using its value in the same expression.

Comment: using ^, like a ^= (b ^= (a ^= b))

Comment: Try looking for xor swap.

Comment: These are **all invalid** and produce undefined behavior.

Comment: It may be possible in some cases but anyone that thinks it's a good idea is a fool.

Answer (score 12):

The frequently cited classic answer that you are probably looking for is:

```
a^=b^=a^=b;
```

**But**, it is technically *wrong*, because it changes the same variable more than once before a sequence point.

Answer (score -1):

Use bit twiddling in C. Following swap two variables:

```
if (a != b) { 
   a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior since the same variable is modified twice.